# Php date function

Tags: php, date

I can't see my location time with following php function:

```
echo date("y-m-d h:m:s A");
```

it's show **12-05-05 08:05:12 AM**  BUT it's **12-05-05 12:40:12 PM NOW**

Can anyoe fix this issue..
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your preferred timezone in **php.ini**:

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = Asia/Manila
```

You can see the list of supported timezones [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).

Or you can go other way, use [`date_default_timezone_set()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php).

Comment: @Shibbir : Remember to accept the answers that fixes your problem

Answer (score 1):

Set setlocale function. [Here this the description](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php)

Answer (score 0):

Fix your server time, or use this:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Answer (score 0):

You are using m, but it's used to represent month, not minutes.

This is probably what you'd like to do:

```
echo date("y-m-d h:i:s A");
```

After that, you're either using the wrong timezone or the servers time is badly setup. If you have access to the server run `date` in a terminal.

Comment: I'm checking it in my localhost but it's still show wrong time.. 4 hours different from my local time.

Comment: Set the default timezone [date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) so that it ticks with your own.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from Blake comment, i suggets try  [fixing your time zone](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php), add +/- time you require
time , example

```
$timediff = 10;

$diff= $timediff+ ($timediff* 60 * 60)
```